# How to whitelist IAM access to APIGateway based on policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have a method enabled with `AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM` in ApiGateway. This works when I supply an AccessKey and SecretKey for an IAM user with the programmatic access policy in the header, however this is only half the desired outcome.

Is there a way to further extend this Authorization to only allow IAM users that have a policy attached for the specific API Gateway method?

My initial thought was to have a resource policy on the API Gateway to deny all requests and then assign method access policies to specific IAM Users to override that, but according to the [Policy Evaluation Logic documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) any resource with an explicit deny overrides the one with the allow.

[image]

Is it possible to restrict API Gateway methods to only the IAM users that have an allow policy for the method, aka "whitelist"?

Comment: i thought when you have AWS_IAM as the authentication. only the users or roles with permission to invoke an endpoint can invoke. not true?

Comment: I can call the API with out giving it explicit access. Is this something to do with programmatic access? I am following this video https://youtu.be/KXyATZctkmQ. I thought I need programmatic access to generate access keys

Comment: i tried this just now. i created a user with no permissions at all. the user could not execute the api. I have updated my posted answer. but one thing i noted, when i make changes to the policy, it took a while to reflect when i was testing it from postman

Comment: and you are right, you need programatic access to generate access keys. console access just lets the user login to aws console.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try with a fresh IAM user tomorrow and see if I get different results.

Comment: @ArunK I made a new IAM user and it's working as expected now. I must have used the wrong acesskeys when I was using this for a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the IAM policy that allows a user to invoke a particular api method. The user cannot invoke the api endpoint without the permissions to invoke.

For testing, I have created a user with no permissions and I have received the below error.

```
{
    "Message": "User: arn:aws:iam::********1111:user/test-api-gateway-iam-auth is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:********1111:b2r0m0gev9/test/GET/"
}
```

I have attached the following policy to an IAM user. The policy allowed the user to invoke a particular api method.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-southeast-2:********1111:xxx/test/GET/"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi. Does boto3 support invoking such api protected by the policy? Just wondering, how one would invoke the api with boto3.

Comment: just trying to understand. the api has an end point url and it can be accessed from any rest client such as curl, post man etc. When you invoke the api url using a rest client, the aws credentials are passed in the form calculated AWS Signature. am i missing something?

Comment: What I mean is that boto3 for lambda has [invoke](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) method to invoke lambda function. But i don't see any equivalent call for api gateway. If you use curl, how do you enforce the IAM credentials of the `test-api-gateway-iam-auth` user? Nothing wrong with the answer. I upvoted it. Just wondering how such policies are used in boto3. Maybe boto3 can't be used for that?

Comment: I have just checked the boto3 documentation. looks like you cant invoke the api gateway method using boto3.  when we execute curl command, the aws access key id and secret key id is not passed directly. Instead an `Authorization` header is passed. The authorizzation header is calculated in a particular way. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Comment: And the curl command will be like this. curl --location --request GET 'https://b2r0m0gev9.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test' \
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20200805T000723Z' \
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAXXXJVG/20200805/ap-southeast-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=bf245b59f3152acded0c683f0d8eb15b0fc000dad7187256de84684bbcbfadb2'

Comment: I see. So you have to manually construct the signature or use some third party tools for that i guess. Thanks for clarification :-) Its strange AWS does not provide such support for invoking policy protected api gateways.

Comment: Yes we have to calculate the signature manually. When i was testing this i used Postman, Postman has a special Authorization method called `AWS Singature`,  it will accept aws access key id, secret access Key id, region and the service name as `execute-api` and calculate the signature and add it to the header on the fly.

Comment: here is how the signature is calculated in python https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html